# Mongo Returns full data while Mongoose does not return relative data

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I use mongo Command Prompt to get data, it works fine:

[image]

But when I do it using mongoose in node.js, I don't get referenced data.

Here is my code:

In Model:

```
module.exports.getOrderBysalesOrderId = function(salesOrderId, callback){
  Order.find({salesOrderId: salesOrderId}).exec(function(err, order){
    if(err) return callback(err, null);
    callback(null, order);
  });
};
```

In Route:

```
router.get('/:salesOrderId', function(req, res, next){

  var salesOrderId = req.param('salesOrderId');

  console.log('order with 1 param is called.');

  Order.getOrderBysalesOrderId(salesOrderId, function(err, order) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        } else {
            //respond to both HTML and JSON. JSON responses require 'Accept: application/json;' in the Request Header
            res.format({

              //response in dust or jade files
              html: function(){
                  res.render('Order', {
                        title: 'Order',
                        "order" : order
                    });
              },

              //JSON response will show all orders in JSON format
              json: function(){
                  res.json(order);
              }
          });
        }
  });
});
```

Then using Ajax, I try to get the data and print it to console:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Order/" + orderNo,
    dataType:"json",
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings)
    {
        console.log(settings.url);
    },
    success: function(order)
    {
      console.log(order);
      templateData = order;
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('ajax loading error... ... '+ url + query);
    }
});
```

Output in Console:

[image]

## Update:

Here is the structure of my model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  salesOrderId: String,
  orderDate: Date,
  party: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Party'},
  items:[{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Item'}, {quantity: Number}, {rate: Number}],
  dispatches:{
    invoiceId: Number,
    dispatchDate: Date,
    items: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Item'}, {quantity: Number}, {rate: Number}]
  }
});
```

## Update2:

When I try to get data using populate(), here  is my query:

```
module.exports.getOrderBysalesOrderId = function(salesOrderId, callback){
  Order.find({salesOrderId: salesOrderId}).populate("items").exec(function(err, order){
    console.log(order);
    if(err) return callback(err, null);
    callback(null, order);
  });
};
```

Here I get error:

[image]

## Update3:

Now I tried the below mentioned code in model:

```
module.exports.getOrderBysalesOrderId = function(salesOrderId, callback){
  salesOrderId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(salesOrderId);
  Order.find({salesOrderId: salesOrderId}).populate("party").exec(function(err, order){
    console.log(order);
    if(err) return callback(err, null);
    callback(null, order);
  });
};
```

Here is my db.js file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/RateDifferenceDB')
```

Now, I get another error:

[image]

I also get a url error in console of browser:

[image]

Comment: can you console.log your salesOrderId in route file, you will be able to know what value you are passing, because the mongo query seems fine.

Comment: @AjitejKaushik I just tried it. It logs fine. Also in the picture of Console you can see that object has got the date correctly, but not the other fields.

Comment: @AjitejKaushik If I print order to Console, in else block of Route, I get an empty array of items as well as dispatches as shown in question.

Comment: @AjitejKaushik I have tried to console.log in Model as well. It also does not return related data.

Comment: if you are expecting only one result, you can use query `Order.findOne` instead of Order.find and moreover i believe when you are interacting with DB the `salesOrderId` you are trying to pass is not the desired one.

Comment: @AjitejKaushik I guarantee that `salesOrderId` is desired one. Now I have tried to use query using populate as: `db.orders.find({salesOrderId: salesOrderId}).populate("items")` And it gives me an error. Just a minute I will update my question.

Comment: need not put db in the network query, it will work  fine with `Order.find`. Do a check in route file before calling the html tag and check what response you are getting.  i have gone through your node code and couldnt find a error so far. Try to put a break point wherever you feel the code may misbehave and then you will be able to track the whole thing where it is going wrong.

Comment: @AjitejKaushik I have updated my question. Can you please check the update and update2 part of question??

Comment: put `var mongoose = require('mongoose');` in your file where you are makinng the network call and put `salesOrderId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(salesOrderId);` before hitting the DB. I believe your salesOrderId is a objectId. Thatswhy you got this error.

Comment: Now I get another error after trying the code changes that you suggested. Please see the Update3 part of question...

Comment: @AjitejKaushik Can you please see url error in update3 part of question???

Comment: this is your javascript error in your ajax call, i dont have pretty handful experience in ajax, i can only guide for node.js

Comment: @AjitejKaushik Just forget about all the errors and please see my main code. In that I just used `.lean()` and I get the results. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should use lean function to get results :

```
module.exports.getOrderBysalesOrderId = function(salesOrderId, callback){
  Order.find({salesOrderId: salesOrderId}).lean().exec(function(err, order){
    if(err) return callback(err, null);
    callback(null, order);
  });
};
```

Comment: but lean returns data in raw form instead of your mongoose model, anyways its working for you, thats great!!

Comment: raw as in unformatted like you must have seen while using postman!

Comment: Thanks @AjitejKaushik for your valuable time and sharing your experience.